# Django "naturalday" template filter: fall back to formatted date?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm using [Django's naturalday template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturalday), but how do I format the date string if the supplied date is not today, tomorrow or yesterday?

This is my template string:

```
 Date: {{ result_date|naturalday }}
```

If `result_date` is today, yesterday or tomorrow, then the template displays the natural string. But if it's 10 days ago, how can I control the formatting of the date to display as "July 25"?

The docs say:

> For dates that are the current day or within one day, return “today”,
>   “tomorrow” or “yesterday”, as appropriate. Otherwise, format the date
>   using the passed in format string.

What does "the passed in format string" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the format after the `:`, like in [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter:

```
Date: {{ result_date|naturalday:"F d" }}
```

- `F` is a textual representation of month, e.g. `July`.
- `d` is a day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros, e.g. `25`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the example:

> Examples (when ‘today’ is 17 Feb 2007):
>
> - 16 Feb 2007 becomes yesterday.
> - 17 Feb 2007 becomes today.
> - 18 Feb 2007 becomes tomorrow.
> - Any other day is formatted according to given argument or the DATE_FORMAT setting if no argument is given.

Then about `DATE_FORMAT`:

> Default: 'N j, Y' (e.g. Feb. 4, 2003)
>
> The default formatting to use for displaying date fields in any part
>   of the system. Note that if USE_L10N is set to True, then the
>   locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied
>   instead. See allowed date format strings.

So it will fall back to `Feb. 17, 2007` if no format string argument is provided and `DATE_FORMAT` is not specified in `settings.py`.

The normal fall back format string is provided in alecxe's answer.